# How can I Improve this Code, using While Loop?

Tags: python

Create a function addNumbers(x) that takes a number as an argument and adds all the integers between 1 and the number (inclusive) and returns the total number.

Examples :

> addNumbers(10)
>     55
>   addNumbers(1)
>     1

So this is a question, I have done using while loop , and it worked fine. But I am not satisfied with my code, I also did this problem using for loop and that's okay for me, but I want to know what could be the best way to improve dis code using while loop.

```
def addNumbers(num):
    total = 1
    i = 1
    while i < num:
          i += 1
          total += i
    return total
print addNumbers(10)
```

And here is my for loop answer :

```
def addNumbers(num):
    my_list = list(range(num+1) )
    for i in my_list:
        my_list.append(i)
        return sum(my_list)
```

Comment: [No loops necessary](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/atp2/arithseq.htm). The answer is simply `num*(num + 1)/2`

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I think you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually SO isn't the place for such questions, but anyway..
You can use `sum()` and `range()`. `range()` will return a list of numbers from `0` to `n` and `sum` will, well, sum it.

```
def sumNumbers(n):
    return sum(range(n+1))
```

**EDIT**: And using `while` loop:

```
def sumNumbers(n):
    i = 0
    sum = 0
    while i <= n:
       sum += i
       i += 1
    return sum
```

Comment: OP asked how he could improve his code *using a while loop*.

Comment: Also, `n` is inclusive, so you need to range till `n+1` .

Comment: Indeed, I fixed my answer.

Comment: ok i am sorry if these questions seems noob, but i am . and thankyou very much for helping me . thankyu all

Comment: well the OP's question sounds more like 'should I use a while loop?' to me

Answer (score 2):

If you want an O(1) algorithm that isn't brute-force, you can use Gauss's method:

```
def sum_numbers(n):
    return (n+1)*n//2
```

Comment: thanks bro, :) , thanks for sharing another kind of answer

Answer (score -1):

Make use of numpy's sum routine and a generator like so,

```
import numpy as np

maxNumber = 10
sumOfNumbers = np.sum([(x) for x in xrange(1, maxNumber+1)])
print sumOfNumbers
```

The generator gives you the list of numbers & the routine adds them for you.

Comment: its that kind of down vote that put me off replying to posts here.